# Showing time from Jquery time-picker after setting custom css effect in few time rows on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timepicker

Having problem to show the timepicker after setting css effects. tried beforeShow method but beforeShow is not also firing though i don't know beforeShow  will work or not for my purpose as i never worked with beforShow.

Now The Scenario is

---

Currently i am setting css effects on clicking the textbox to show timepicker, so as i am getting the available time with jquery ajax call & then setting css effect on those time so as a result on clicking  textbox the css effects are displaying later & having flickering effect which i don,t know .  i want to show the timepicker dropdown after setting all the css effects.

**This is how i am setting the TimePicker**

```
    $(".txtArrivalTime").timePicker({

        startTime: "05:30",
        step: 15

       , onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

          // console.log(dateText);
       }
//, beforeShow () {
//}
    });
```

**This is how i am setting the css Effects**

```
 // Highlight Available Time Slots
$(".txtArrivalTime").click(function () {
    $(".time-picker>ul>li.AvaiableTime").removeClass("AvaiableTime");
    $(".time-picker>ul>li.RemoveAvailableTime").removeClass("RemoveAvailableTime");

    var custID = $("#hfCustomerID").val();
    var realdate = $("#txtExamDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var date = $("#txtExamDate").val();
    date = date == "Locked" ? "" : date
    var DayOfWeek = realdate ? realdate.getDay() : null;

    //$("#time_07_00").css("background-color", "gray");



    $.ajax({
        url: "/Data/Services/CustomersUsers.asmx/GetCustomerTimeSlots",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ID: custID, DayOfWeek: DayOfWeek, ShowInactive: false, SelectedDate: date }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            data = data.d;
            if (data.hasAnySlots && data.slots.length) {

                $.each(data.slots, function (i, slot) {
                    var Hrs = "00" + slot.timeSlot.Hours;
                    Hrs = Hrs.substr(Hrs.length - 2);
                    var Mins = "00" + slot.timeSlot.Minutes;
                    Mins = Mins.substr(Mins.length - 2);
                    var time = Hrs + ":" + Mins;
                    var rtime = time.replace(':', '_');
                    $("#time_" + rtime).removeClass("RemoveAvailableTime");
                    $("#time_" + rtime).addClass("AvaiableTime");
                });

            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Data/Services/CustomersUsers.asmx/GetTakenCustomerTimes",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ custID: custID, date: date, poid: $("#patientOrderID").val() }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    data = data.d;

                    $.each(data, function (i, slot) {
                        var Hrs = "00" + slot.Hours;
                        Hrs = Hrs.substr(Hrs.length - 2);
                        var Mins = "00" + slot.Minutes;
                        Mins = Mins.substr(Mins.length - 2);
                        var time = Hrs + ":" + Mins;
                        var rtime = time.replace(':', '_');
                        $("#time_" + rtime).removeClass("AvaiableTime");
                        $("#time_" + rtime).addClass("RemoveAvailableTime");
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });


});
```

***//Note : Available Time That i am getting with  ajax call to get time and set css effects on those time in timepicker does depend on the txtExamDate Text.***

Please tell me a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally I have fixed it myself. i had to write the same code for change event of txtExamDate instead of click event of txtArrivalTime. :) sorry for my bad.. that was so easy.